# pd.pivot_table() is unable to compute statistics on datetime64[ns]

Tags: pandas

The following code creates a `pd.DataFrame` with two columns, `date` and `category`. The `date` column is set to use the `datetime64[ns]` type.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data={'date': pd.Series(['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', 
                      '2021-01-03'], dtype='datetime64[ns]'), 'category': ['A', 'B', 'C']})
```

Pandas allows computing numeric statistics over the `date` column:

```
>>> df['date'].min()
Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00')
>>> df['date'].median()
Timestamp('2021-01-02 00:00:00')
>>> df['date'].mean()
Timestamp('2021-01-02 00:00:00')
```

However, when I create a pivot_table, it is unable to compute statistics, like `mean` or `median`, over the `date` column:

```
>>> df.pivot_table(['date'], ['category'], aggfunc='median')
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "/home/dmitry/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 1121, in _cython_agg_blocks
    raise DataError("No numeric types to aggregate")
pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

However, `min`/`max` works just fine:

```
>>> df.pivot_table(['date'], ['category'], aggfunc='min')
               date
category           
A        2021-01-01
B        2021-01-02
C        2021-01-03
```

Do you know what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the datetime to int64 and then turn it back after the pivot_table.

```
df.astype({'date': 'int64'}).pivot_table(values=['date'], index=['category'], aggfunc='median').astype('datetime64[ns]')
```